# How to extract keys corresponding to some particular value in a dataframe consisting of key value pairs as shown in the description below

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I have a dataframe column like this. It has some keywords and corresponding values. I want to extract the key and value pair where value is greater than 500 and I also want to print highest of overall dataset and corresponding key.

| Frequency |
| --- |
| PM : 100, AM : 587 |
| GH : 257, PM : 675, JK : 843 |
| AM : 54 , JK : 754, GH : 100, PO : 86 |
| MN : 567 |
| PM : 1023 |
| ML : 200 |

I tried

```
for i, row in df.iterrows:
    freq= row['Frequency']
    
    #This line is showing error for lines where comma not there, means single key: value.
    frequency = dict(item.split(':') for item in freq.strip().split(','))

    max_freq_keyword = [key for key,value in frequency.items() if int(value.strip()) >= 500]
```

But it's also not working. Can anyone tell me the best pythonic way to extract things like this.

Answer (score 0):

One issue in your data is that they are having spaces, please be careful while parsing, otherwise the code below works fine in my case

```
# craete dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"Frequency":["PM : 100, AM : 587", "GH : 257, PM : 675, JK : 843","AM : 54 , JK : 754, GH : 100, PO : 86", "MN : 567","PM : 1023","ML : 200"]})
# parse and create a dummy column having dictionary
df['freq'] = [dict(item.split(':') for item in freq.strip().split(',')) for freq in df['Frequency'].values]
# filter pairs from freq column where value is gt 500
df['gt500_pair'] = [{k:int(v.strip()) for k,v in y.items() if int(v.strip())>500 } for y in df['freq'].values]  ## here i have removed space from value strings and converted to int

#  Till this point you have answer to part-1 of your question, let's get the pair having max value throughout the data frame 

# Now row wise get the max values (from filtered pairs) 
df['max_eachrow'] = [max(x.values()) if len(x)>0 else 0  for x in df['gt500_pair'].values]
#max(df['max_eachrow'])  o/p: 1023
```

[image]

```
# find idxmax (find index where max value for a column found)
df['max_eachrow'].idxmax()  # o/p : 4  # so row 4 has max value in whole dataframe
# now go to the index and find it
df[['gt500_pair']].loc[df['max_eachrow'].idxmax()]
# o/p: {'PM ': 1023}
```

Let me know if anything is not clear

Comment: Value error: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
This error I am getting for the line :df['freq'] = [dict(item.split(':') for item in freq.strip().split(',')) for freq in df['Frequency'].values]

Comment: Basically that step is to convert the string  like "AM : 54 , JK : 754, GH : 100, PO : 86" to a dictionary structure,  my guess is you have null/empty strings in the Frequency column, so instead of that line, you can derive the dictionary by a iterrow() and parsing code inside with exception handling in that, (put a empty dict for failure cases).  Because i have not checked your complete dataset, i cannot say anything confidently,   once you have dictionary like values(pairs) in "freq" column, my code works fine. Try by yourself and keep posted the issues. will try to answer.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Thank you